# Idempotent Matrix non diagonal terms as a function of diagonal terms

Tags: matrices

Assuming the construction of an idempotent symmetric matrix ($=^$ and $=^2$). Is there any way to write the terms of this matrix as a function of its diagonal terms ?

For a 3x3 matrix, the solution is easy :
$$
^2_{12}=A^2_{21}=(1−_{22}−_{33})(1−_{11}−_{33})
$$
$$
^2_{13}=A^2_{31}=(1−_{22}−_{33})(1−_{11}−_{22})
$$
$$
^2_{23}=A^2_{32}=(1−_{11}−_{33})(1−_{11}−_{22})
$$

However, I am stuck on the computation for a 4x4 matrix or a generalization of the solution.

Comment: These $A$ are very special. They are of the form $A = U\Delta U^T$ with $U$ an arbitrary orthonormal matrix and $\Delta$ a diagonal matrix with $0$ and $1$ as diagonal elements. If $n$ is the dimension of $A$, then we have $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ elements $A_{ij}$ with $i < j$ that have to be appropriate functions of the $n$ diagonal elements. Since $\frac{n(n-1)}{2} > n$ for $n \geq 4$ I think this is impossible.

Comment: @DieterKadelka That's true, although if you assume the rank ( = sum of diagonal entries) is small, like 1 or so, it gets easier.

Comment: Dear all thank you  for your feedback. I have succeeded to solve the system for a 4x4 matrix. However I’m not sure it is possible for bigger ones